# Any solution for Windows 10 sound problem on MacBook Pro Late 2011?

Tags: audio, windows

I have been able to install windows 10 on my MacBook Pro Late 2011, thanks to all your earlier posts, however i have been unable to fix the sound problem after installation. Please if anyone can give me workable solution for this problem.

Thanks All.

Comment: Please edit your question with the **exact** symptoms of the sound problem. You've just told your doctor "my tummy hurts" and given no more information. And as we can't get our hands on your system you have to be *DESCRIPTIVE*.

Comment: I common cause of lack of sound occurs when UEFI installing windows on your  model Mac. Do you know if you installed to BIOS or UEFI boot?